# Laravel 5.2 project artisan error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have Laravel 5.2 project and when I'm trying to install it to my home computer, I have some troubles with it. All steps what I do are next below:

First I clone project by command:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/.../...
```

Then I try to install project requires by command

```
composer install
```

and have this error

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

After creating and configuring `.env` file a have next error

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test_db.tasks' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`deleted_at` is null)

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test_db.tasks' doesn't exist
```

And now when I try to make any `php artisan` command I have this error.

I found at Laracasts that I have to comment all my own ServiceProvider but that did not solve my problem.

Comment: Solve, in App\Console\Kernel.php in func schedule has code, that trying to perform when I type only **php artisan**, why, I don't know.

Comment: Rather than post your solution as a [comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), please [post an answer to your own question](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This makes it easier for other users to find the answer, and to see that your problem has been solved. (You will be able to [accept](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your answer after a couple days.)